# "dp" Issue in Xamarin Android Layer-List with multiple Rectangles

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin

I'm using Xamarin Android in Visual Studio and trying to do a simple task of displaying two rectangles, one above the other. When I use a measure size of "px" everything works as expected, but when I use "dp", the second rectangle does not get rendered. Here's my xml file with the rectangles:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:top="0dp" >
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#6EF562" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:top="57dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#000000" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

**Note the "dp" above. That code does not work. But if changed to "px", it works as expected.**

Here's the source of my Main.axml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#E6EDF0"
android:paddingTop="50dp">
<Button
    android:id="@+id/MyButton"
    android:layout_width="178.1dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Hello"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:background="@drawable/splitColors" />
```

Obviously, I want to use "dp" rather than pixels "px" for scaling reasons taking into different device form factors, but I can't get this to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The height of the button, is set at `wrap_content`. And in your drawable you specify you want to draw the black bottom part at 57dp. So if you're button smaller than 57dp it will never show. That's why it does the job at pixels, because 57px isn't that high. So if you want to use DP make sure your button is at least as high as the value you give `<item android:top="57dp">`